# Issues Cleaning Up a Git Repository

Tags: git, bfg-repo-cleaner

I have a private remote git repository, which I have been using for a project for years. In the course of some testing and bug fixing, I inadvertently uploaded some very large files (MySQL dumps, each dump > 100 MB) and 2 directories with test files (total 8 GB). I now cannot clone or update the repository. That was a few commits ago, not the current commit. Once I realized the issue, I added entries to .gitignore (*.sql, MemorabiliaJSON/documents, designs/)

I was looking into how to remove these two folders and files. The BFG seemed to be promising, but I can't even get past step 1:

```
$ git clone --mirror <path to repo>memorabilia-JSON.git
Cloning into bare repository 'memorabilia-JSON.git'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 15031, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (15031/15031), done.
error: pack-objects died of signal 9782/13739)   
error: git upload-pack: git-pack-objects died with error.
fatal: git upload-pack: aborting due to possible repository corruption on the remote side.
remote: aborting due to possible repository corruption on the remote side.
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

git-filter-branch is another option, but seems more fraught with the opportunity for mistakes.

Any idea on how I can remove these large directories and the *.sql files? Is there something else going on that is causing this problem?

Thanks!

Mark

UPDATE:
Taking  Kay's advice, I did a local mirror copy of my remote repository on the remote machine that houses the remote repository. There, I used BFG and git-statistics to trim the mirrored remote repository from 8GB to 145MB. I then looked in the git log for both the updated mirrored repository and the local repository on my local machine (not the remote machine), and found that the last 4 commits from my local repo are not in the updated mirrored remote repo. So, I am at a crossroads....

Option 1
push the updated mirrored repo to the remote repo, so now it is fixed. I think that if I commit the local repo to the updated remote, all the big files will be included (since they are in my local git repo) and I am back to where I started.

Option 2
Start over, mirror my local repo, fix it using the process I used for the mirrored remote repo, push the updated mirrored local repo to my local repo so now the local repo is clean, and the last 4 commits are in place. Then I push my local repo to the remote to replace the remote with the update local repo, and now the remote is clean and the 4 missing commits are in place in the remote.

Does Option 2 sound like the best course of action? I am not a git expert, so I am a bit uncertain about how this all works, and worried I may lose all 138 commits in my local repo!

Thanks,

Mark

Comment: Do you currently have a 1:1 local copy of your remote repository? Because in that case, you should be able to mirror your local copy and work on that.

Comment: OK, that worked doing it locally on the machine that houses the remote repo. I used BFG and git-statistics to trim the whole repository from 8GB to 145 MB. However, when I looked at the git log, I see that the remote repo failed to include the last 4 commits I made this week from my local machine. Just to check my logic, should I mirror the repo on my local machine, do the BFG steps, and then push that to the local repo and also the remote repo?

Comment: I experimented with this a bit myself earlier and came to the conclusion that "unlinking" the original local working dir/repo/copy from any remotes *before* doing the mirroring was the least confusing (given I didn't have time to explore this in-depth). It's that a mirror clone appears to know about any remotes which are present on a local original, but it does not list them the usual way (with `git config --list`), and I didn't have time to find out if they can be removed, and how. But in my case it also refused to push to those, and only updated its (local) source.

Comment: In your current case, I'd make sure to make a copy of your original local repo to avoid data loss (though I'm assuming this was your very first step anyway), then push the now updated mirror clone to your local original – if you just do `git push`, your mirror should tell you it won't update the hidden refs, i.e. the remotes, and only update the local original. Then I guess you'd just continue working with your local original again, were you'd (force) push your local branches to your remote, including those last 4 commits which only exist locally so far.

Comment: Hmm, I should probably add a summary of all the above as a proper reply...

Comment: I may have not been clear on where I am. I will update the original post to make it clearer. Please check that out.